# Leaflet overlapping polygons merge before applying opacity

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet, geojson

I have a leaflet map to which I add hundreds of polygons. It happens sometimes that there are numerous polygons overlapping at the same point, adding their opacity and in the end making it impossible to see the base map.

[image: A minimum example of overlapping polygons adding their opacity]

The way I add the polygons to the map is as follows:

```
map = L.map('map');
var coveragePane = map.createPane('coverage');
coveragePane.style.opacity = 0.2;

let geojsonBlue = L.geoJson(data, 
  {
    stroke: false, 
    // fillOpacity: 0.25,
    fillColor: "#0000FF",
    zIndex: 25,
   }
);
geojsonBlue.addTo(map, {pane: 'coverage'});
```

As can be seen in the above code I have tried [adding the polygons with full opacity to a pane and then setting the opacity of the pane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41769404/leaflet-how-to-control-opacity-of-layer-groups) to be transparent. This however seems to recursively set the opacity of the layers and not the whole pane as one solid layer.

Previously I have also tried merging the polygons using Turf.js union which gave a good result. This however is computationally expensive and impractical for hundreds of polygons. It also makes it difficult to dynamically add and remove layers one by one.

Is there another way one can merge the rendered polygons (in the rasterized world, not the vector world) before applying the transparency/opacity.

[One question mentions D3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334135/leaflet-overlapping-shapes-opacity), but I'm not sure if that is relevant for polygons.

I'm also thinking of rendering the polygons to PNG map tiles on the server and serving the rasterized tiles out and applying the opacity to them. But what tool can I use on the server to do this?

[See this example of what I'm trying to fix.](https://ttnmapper.org/staging.php?zoom=14&lat=52.3720&lon=4.9055)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there another way one can merge the rendered polygons (in the rasterized world, not the vector world) before applying the transparency/opacity?

Use a `L.Canvas` as the target `L.Renderer` for the polygons, then apply the opacity to the corresponding `HTMLCanvasElement` or one of its parents - e.g. the Leaflet pane containing the `HTMLCanvasElement`.

e.g.:

```
map.createPane('semitransparent');
map.getPane('semitransparent').style.opacity = '0.5';
var canvasRenderer = L.canvas({pane: 'semitransparent'});
L.polygon(..., {renderer: canvasRenderer}).addTo(map);
L.polygon(..., {renderer: canvasRenderer}).addTo(map);
```

It's kinda a hack, but should work for your use case.

Comment: I implemented your suggestion but it seems not to work. You are welcome to check the source of https://ttnmapper.org/staging.php and see what I did. Your code can be seen on line 100, 488 and 555.

Comment: Yeah it's working. Basically the missing piece of the puzzle was to force the layer's opacity to 1, otherwise it will use a default semi transparent one that will multiply by the pane's opacity. Thanks a lot @IvanSanchez!